# Vs code docker extension won't see c# extension installed

Tags: c#, docker, visual-studio-code

I am trying to make my ASP.NET Core application work with docker containers, so I've tried generating docker files via Docker extension in vs code using *command pallet add dockerfile or docker-compose files* -  Badly, I get an error `Cannot generate Dockerfiles for a .NET project unless version 1.23.9 or higher of the C# extension is installed.` - even though I've installed it and tried some things to fix it (Like reinstalling extensions, vs code app and searching for answers elsewhere). I am using windows and I have docker installed and running when I am trying the scaffolding operation.

[Here is a screenshot where you can see I am, in fact, have these extensions installed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8sd4.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue and solved it by downgrading the C# extension to 1.23.9 and restarting VS Code.

[VS Code Extensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b13bu.png)